# Failed to fetch vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, get, frontend, fetch-api

I add this code at `mounted()`:

```
mounted() {
fetch('http://127.0.0.1/logined')
    .then(
        function(response) {
          if (response.status !== 200) {
            console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
                response.status);
            return;
          }

          // Examine the text in the response
          response.json().then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
          });
        }
    )
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
    });
}
```

It's not fixing, API works well.
API returns
`{'result':'false'}`

Console Log

[image: Console Log]

This problem not fixing for me, I tried at another PC but same.
Axios is not working too so I changed to fetch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with your code, the error you showed in your screenshot says you cannot get any result from the URL.
It looks like your browser is under CORS policy and this is why it doesn't work or you use `GET` instead of `POST`.

Comment: Thanks, My backend server was problem.

Comment: I solved with cors header!